# How to configure IIS-5 (on windows xp) to behave similar to AppPool in win servers & windows 7. (Integrated Security=true)

Tags: iis, database-connection, iis-5, application-pool, integrated-security

I use windows xp and IIS 5 for web development. For database connection the credentials are set up as Integrated Security. It works fine our our DEV server (IIS 6) where they have configured the App Pool to run under the context of a domain account which has dbo access on the database. I myself also have dbo access in the database.

But when I run from my localhost the database connection failed (under Integrated Security=true) saying user '' has no previleged. So its passing a blank string as user instead of my logged in domain accountj ("domainname\myname"). How do I configure my localhost IIS so that it passed my logged in domain account as a user to the sql server? Basically I'm trying to silumate the apppool on  IIS-5in my local machine.

I tried changing the "Log on as" on World wide web services & IIS Admin on my local machine services console, restarted it and did an IISRESET. Nothing seems to fix the problem. 
Also I tried putting my domain user name (domainname\username) and password in the connection string by removing integreated security=true. Still that also not works

I am an administrator on my local machine. I tried different things like making aspnet user an administrator,log as as service  etc etc with no luck

Please advice me how to configure IIS5 to run under a different account. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the user for anonymous login to be the domain account.  I forget what tab it is on but it is there somewhere.

I think this link will point you in the correct direction
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310344

Answer (score 0):

Use [IIS Express](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/) -- it is IIS7 for XP.